# Deriving mappings from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Give continuous functions $f,g,h,k:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and sets $U,C,K,S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that:

(a) $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ but $f(U)$ is not.

This one is easy in my mind, I let $U=(0,2\pi)$ then $f(x)=\sin(x)$ then $f:(0,\pi)\rightarrow [-1,1]$

(b) $C$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ but $g(C)$ is not.

This one is more tricky. I figure the interval $[0,\infty)$ is closed because its compliment is open. But I can't think of a function. My original thought was $\ln(x)$, but the domain doesn't work.

(c) $K$ is compact but $h^{-1}(K)$ is not.

A metric space $M$ is compact if, for every collection $C$ of open sets such that $\cup C=M$, there are elements $U_1,\dots,U_n\in C$ such that $U_1\cup\dots\cup U_n= M$. I struggle to understand this definition fully, but I do know that intervals $[a,b]$ are compact. I also know that if a set in $\mathbb{Q}$ is compact if and only if the set is finite. So would a function that maps $[a,b]\in\mathbb{R}$ to $[a',b']\in\mathbb{Q}$ work? Since $[a',b']\in\mathbb{Q}$ would have infinitely many points.

(d) $S$ is connected but $k^{-1}(S)$ is not.

A subset $M\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is connected iff and only if $a,b\in M$ and $a<b$ then $[a,b]\subseteq M$. So basically any interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is connected right? I also know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not connected. So I'm thinking that a if I find a function that maps an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ to at a set of at least two rational numbers, then I take the inverse of that function and that will be my answer.

Comment: For (c), consider $h(x) = 0$. $K=\{0\}$ is compact. Re (d), a set of at least two rationals containing only rationals can't be the image of an interval by a continuous function, $k$ will have to map the interval onto one point only. Instead, how about the absolute value function.

Comment: a: Let $U=\mathbb{R}, f(x)=1$

b:Let $U=\mathbb{R}, g(x)=e^x$

Comment: Error in (a): $f((0,\pi)) = (0,1].$

Comment: c. Think about $\sin x$, $K = $[-1,1].$

Comment: d: $S=\{1\}, k(x)=x^2\Rightarrow k^{-1}(1)=\{-1,+1\}\text{is not connceted}$

Comment: @RaziehNoori Should be $S = \{1\}.$ Also the inverse image is not correct. Why not just use $x^2.$

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. (a) is corrected. So I take it $\mathbb{R}$ is closed because its compliment is the empty set which is open?

Comment: @Burgundy by definition let $X$ be a set and let $τ$ be a family of subsets of $X$. Then $τ$ is called a topology on $X $ if:
Both the empty set and $X$ are elements of $τ$...., thus since here $X= \mathbb{R}$ thus $\mathbb{R}$ is open

Comment: Ok thank you, So then your comment for (b) will not work then since $\mathbb{R}$ is open, but it is asking for a closed set. But $e^x$ gives insight. Thank you

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is open and closed. use complement of empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $2)$, consider $C = [0,\infty)$ and $g(x) = \exp(-x)$. Then, $g(C) = (0,1]$ which is not closed. The reasoning behind such a choice is that we know that if our function is continuous and if the to-be-mapped set is closed **and** bounded, then it's compact and so will be its image by our continuous function. So, we should think of an **unbounded** closed set, and any function with an asymptote would do the job.

For $3)$, a subset of $\mathbb R$ is compact if and only if it's closed and bounded. Now, a continuous function always pulls back a closed set to a closed set; so the challenge here is to find a compact whose inverse image is unbounded. Note also that a continuous function always maps compacts to compacts, so your function must either have no inverse on the domain or a discontinuous inverse (there are continuous functions with discontinuous inverses). How about $h(x) = \sin(x)$, with $K = [-1,1]$?

For $4)$, the connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ are the ones that are intervals. So you have to search for an interval whose inverse image is not an interval. Also note that a continuous function preserves connectedness; so your function must not have an inverse on the domain, or it should have a discontinuous inverse. So, we would think about a set like $S = (0,1)$ and a function such as $k(x) = x^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Why is it that $k^{-1}(S)$ in this case is not connect? Obviously $k^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x}$, but doesn't this just map $(0,1)$ to itself?

Comment: @Burgundy $k^{-1}$ doesn't exist if we are looking at $k: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. It only exists on $[0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0]$. The inverse image of $S$ by $k$ here is $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$.

Comment: You probably know that, but just as a reminder, $k^{-1}(S)$ is not the image of $S$ by the inverse function of $k$. We can talk about the inverse image without the function being invertible. By definition, $k^{-1}(A) = \{x, k(x) \in A\}$.